# How to change the Databin file name?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

You can create a Databin file like this:

[image]

[This link](https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/admin) can check you file.I found I couldn't change it's name after I create it.As the documemtation of `RenameFile` in **Details and Options**:

> RenameFile works on cloud objects, changing their cloud file names but
>   not their UUIDs.

So I guess it can do this.But how to do it?

Comment: @Xavier `bin["Name"]` can get its name,but it's invariable after use `SetOptions`.Strange behavior.

Comment: @Xavier Wow,I can reproduce it.If you cancel you deletion.I will accept that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a `Databin`

```
bin = CreateDatabin["Name" -> "FirstName"];

bin["Name"]
(* "FirstName" *)
```

can be changed with `SetOptions`:

```
SetOptions[bin, "Name" -> "LastName"];
```

The modification does not seem to be reflected when evaluating again the above:

```
bin["Name"]
(* "FirstName" *)
```

and the summary box also still displays the old name:

```
bin
```

[image]

It can be checked however that the change is indeed performed by going on the datadrop [website](https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/admin):

- before the evaluation of `SetOptions`:

[image]

- after its evaluation and reloading the page:

[image]

Note that if we exit the kernel,

```
LocalSymbol["BinUUID"] = bin["UUID"];
Exit
```

and load the bin in a new session, we recover the new name:

```
bin = Databin[LocalSymbol["BinUUID"]]
```

[image]

```
Remove[LocalSymbol["BinUUID"]];

bin["Name"]
(* "LastName" *)
```

**Update**

Alternatively, all the cache related to the bin can be clear:

```
SetOptions[bin, "Name" -> "MiddleName"];

bin["Name"]
(* LastName *)

DownValues[DataDropClient`Private`datadropclientcache] = 
   With[{sid = bin["ShortID"], uuid = bin["UUID"]}, 
      DeleteCases[
        DownValues[DataDropClient`Private`datadropclientcache], 
        patt : HoldPattern[lhs_ :> rhs_] /; MemberQ[patt, sid | uuid , Infinity]
      ]
   ];

bin["Name"]
(* MiddleName *)
```

or the relevant part can be updated appropriately:

```
SetOptions[bin, "Name" -> "NoName"];

DataDropClient`Private`datadropclientcache[{"DatabinIDs", bin["UUID"]}] = 
     Options[bin][[1, 2]]

bin["Name"]
(* "NoName" *)
```